# Android Studio 3.4, 4.1 are unable to start adb on windows 7

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I've went through the complete forum's stackoverflow, github, google, and found many solution out of which many voted + for checking Antivirus blockage for adb
So I uninstalled my genuine Malwarebytes antivirus.
Many voted to kill & restart the adb server using commands
`adb kill-server && adb start-server` likewise.

After getting into forums too seriously I've seen that driver's issue.

Now am having Advanced Driver Updator. And **everything is up to date**
So why am still getting the error.
Have tried to quote the error but am not getting error message,
Only I can see a pop-up cmd and it quits automatically as shown in Video.

and obviously I am using frameworks to build mobile apps, but frameworks runs on top of the core android studio setup

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qI0CM1N8H5uH1a1G4J4bP_ixJxDcdg2C/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IDiCXd03CfmNel06ZCMf72QhdpIYz8QJ/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Added the videos in an iframe snippet.
I wish to get it resolved soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be that code iframe won't play, but going on the link could make know detailed problem am facing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vOcZ5ATFQFOYcdzQtf9d2yRYPO78nPzP/view?usp=sharing
Find the video in the above link & help me if possible issues could be tackled.
Yesterday I've formatted my PC but still, the issue is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.
Just removed a complete setup & android studio woke up finally with debug bridge i.e ADB